# Python 2.7 & wget error 17 "No usable temporary file name found"

Tags: python-2.7, download, wget

I am just learning python 2.7 and trying to use wget to download a file from a URL.

I get the following error (and here are the exact input & syntax):

```
    Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

    >>> import wget
    >>> wget.download('http://www.csun.edu/~rd436460/Labview/Lecture-Overview.pdf')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 506, in download
    (fd, tmpfile) = tempfile.mkstemp(".tmp", prefix=prefix, dir=".")
    File "C:\Python27\lib\tempfile.py", line 314, in mkstemp
    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\tempfile.py", line 257, in _mkstemp_inner
    raise IOError, (_errno.EEXIST, "No usable temporary file name found")
    IOError: [Errno 17] No usable temporary file name found
    >>>
```

My question is....... What is the correct syntax to get this file to download without error?

I am running Python 2.7 On Windows 10......  Also I saw some of the other post of temporary file errors due to no drive space.  On my system I have plenty of drive space available.

Comment: can you try: `import tempfile; print(tempfile._candidate_tempdir_list())` and tell us what it returns? Also can you check your `%TEMP%` directory and remove all the files you can?

Comment: Here is what I get...........

Comment: >>> import tempfile; print(tempfile._candidate_tempdir_list())
['C:\\Users\\DESKTO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', 'C:\\Users\\DESKTO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', 'c:\\temp', 'c:\\tmp', '\\temp', '\\tmp', 'C:\\Windows\\System32']

Comment: What next?  My hard drive has plenty of room....

Comment: can you type in a cmd prompt 2 things? `echo %USERNAME%` and `echo %TEMP%`. And can you check if this path exists: `C:\Users\\DESKTO~1\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: Here is the results:



        >>> echo %USERNAME%
          File "<stdin>", line 1
            echo %USERNAME%
                          ^
        SyntaxError: invalid syntax
        >>> echo %TEMP%
          File "<stdin>", line 1
            echo %TEMP%
                      ^
        SyntaxError: invalid syntax
        >>>



I can confirm the directory "C:\Users\\DESKTO~1\AppData\Local\Temp" does not exist on my computer.

What whould be the next steps to resolve this issue downloading with wget?

Comment: about the echo commands, I meant in a cmd not in python prompt! We're on to something now. Please do the echos in a command prompt without python running.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32>echo %USERNAME%
Desktop-Homey

C:\Windows\System32>echo %TEMP%
C:\Users\DESKTO~1\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: What next.  Thanks for the tip....  I really am an infant beginner to python

Comment: Thanks.  I decided to delete the contents of the folder and try the wget again.  This time it downloaded without error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Not sure why............ It worked and now it will not work.  Gives same error as before even though temp directory is empty....  Any thoughts....